# What caused this error ? (too many arguments) Flutter

Tags: flutter

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments

Is a constant issue I had when developing my Flutter App. What are the common causes?

I hope I'm not asking for something very silly. And lastly I would like to thank anyone that takes their time to answer.

Comment: it may be optional parameter

Comment: You need to show code. The question is too broad as it is.

Answer (score 2):

When I was begining in flutter I also get often stuck at this sort of errors.This happens when you give positional arguments to some widgets instead of the named arguments,
Sometimes some widgets may have very obvious positional arguments For example we can take the case of the Text Widget .

```
Text(
"Hello World",
textAlign: TextAlign.left,
)
```

Here the "Hello world" is a positional argument and `textAign:` is a named argument.

Some most common mistake which cause this error is example:

in a Row there is a named argument called `children` which takes list of widgets instead of using it we may directly start creating children widgets inside row

Your Case Maybe different so check for this sort of mistakes maybe you have given a positional argument were it should be a named argument.

Answer (score 0):

A function has to be provided with exact same number of arguments that it expects(unless they are optional).
For example:

```
void test(String one, String twp) {
  print(one);
  print(two);
}
```

Will not run until is has two arguments passed to it as follows: `test("one", "two");`

In your case, you are providing the function with a parameter when it doesn't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using the children widget
see my code

```
Row(
    children: [
        Text(
             "Area of focus",
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
         ),
    ],
)
```